# Permutations, iterator, recursion and double loop

Tags: python

Here is a function that iterates over permutations of letters in a string:

```
def permutations(items):
    for x in _permutations_rec('', items, len(items)):
        yield x

def _permutations_rec(current, items, n):
    if len(current) == n:
        yield current
    else:
        for item, other_items in pick_item(items):
            for next_ in _permutations_rec(current+item, other_items, n):
                yield next_

def pick_item(items):
    for i, item in enumerate(items):
        yield item, items[:i] + items[i+1:]

# print permutations
for x in permutations('abc'):
    print x
```

In `_permutations_rec` in `else` part, I have two loops. In the first one I
pick the next item that I append to the `current` string. The second loop
iterates the next partial results and yields them.  So, the second `for` is only to
handle the iterator for the recursive call and "bubble-up" its results.
I have found this pattern frequently when yielding results from recursive calls, e.g. when working with [backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking).

Question:

Is there an idiomatic, elegant way to use only one loop there, instead of two? Although I know there is nothing wrong there with those two loops, maybe there is some iterator kung-fu that would allow me to use only one (the simpler, the better).

**Edit:**

- I know `itertools.permutations`, my `permutations` is just a toy example

Comment: About your edit: sorry, that was just for saying in case you didn't know...

Comment: Sorry me, I should have made it clear earlier in my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In modern Python, you can use [yield from](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380) to avoid the innermost loop.  Time to upgrade? :^)

```
    for item, other_items in pick_item(items):
        yield from _permutations_rec(current+item, other_items, n)
```

Comment: When I was young, python2.7 was sufficient for everything! What this world turned to! :)

Answer (score 3):

Because ["simple is better than complex"](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), you can simply use [itertools.permutations](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
from itertools import permutations

for p in permutations('abc'):
    print(p)
```

Output:

```
('a', 'b', 'c')
('a', 'c', 'b')
('b', 'a', 'c')
('b', 'c', 'a')
('c', 'a', 'b')
('c', 'b', 'a')
```

If you still want to use your function, yo can use the new python3's `yield from` statement as [@DSM explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126413/permutations-iterator-recursion-and-double-loop/16126462#16126462).

Answer (score 0):

A shorter version of your, almost the same:

```
In [1]: def permutations(items):
   ....:     if len(items) == 0:
   ....:         yield items
   ....:     else:
   ....:         for n in range(len(items)):
   ....:             for ps in permutations(items[:n]+items[n+1:]):
   ....:                 yield ps + items[n:n+1]
   ....:

In [2]: list(permutations('abc'))
Out[2]: ['cba', 'bca', 'cab', 'acb', 'bac', 'abc']

In [3]: list(permutations(list('abc')))
Out[3]:
[['c', 'b', 'a'],
 ['b', 'c', 'a'],
 ['c', 'a', 'b'],
 ['a', 'c', 'b'],
 ['b', 'a', 'c'],
 ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

BTW: The equivalent code in Scala as following:

```
scala> def perm[T](xs: List[T]): Iterator[List[T]] = xs match {
     |   case Nil => Iterator(Nil)
     |   case _ => for(x <- xs.iterator; ys <- perm(xs diff Seq(x))) yield x::ys
     | }
perm: [T](xs: List[T])Iterator[List[T]]
scala> val itr = perm(List.range(0,100))
itr: Iterator[List[Int]] = non-empty iterator

scala> itr.next
res0: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26,
 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56,
 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86,
 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99)
scala> perm(1::2::3::Nil) foreach println
List(1, 2, 3)
List(1, 3, 2)
List(2, 1, 3)
List(2, 3, 1)
List(3, 1, 2)
List(3, 2, 1)
```